# Copiando o conteúdo de um arquivo para vetores em c

Tags: c, arquivo

Gente, estou tentando copiar um arquivo que possui vários produtos, uma linha com o nome e as seguintes com o código, preço e quantidade. Tentei passar cada linha para um vetor, mas não está funcionando. Quando imprimo, não está correto.

```
 fp = fopen("Produtos.txt","r");

if ((fp = fopen("Produtos.txt","r")) == NULL ){
     printf("Erro na abertura do arquivo!!!!");
     return (0);
}
while (1){
    if(feof(fp)) break;

    fgets(nome_prod[i],100,fp);
    fgets(cod_prod[i],100,fp);
    fscanf(fp,"%f",&preco_prod[i]);
    fscanf(fp,"%d",&quant_prod[i]);
    i++;}
```

Comment: C é diferente de C#, favor usar as tags corretamente.

Comment: como você tá declarando as variáveis nome_prod e cod_prod?

Comment: char nome_prod[1000][100];

Comment: char cod_prod[1000][100];

Comment: Poderias mostrar um exemplo da formatação da entrada?

Answer (score 0):

Eu trocaria as funções que você está utilizando para capturar os dados do arquivo.

```
  char nome_prod[100];
  char cod_prod[100];
  int quant_prod;
  float preco_prod;

  while (1){

     if(feof(fp)) break;

     fread(&nome_prod,1,100,fp);
     fread(&cod_prod,1,100,fp);
     fread(&quant_prod,1,4,fp);
     fread(&preco_prod,1,4,fp);
  }
```

Não tenho certeza se é seu objetivo, mas se seu objetivo é trazer as informações do produto para dentro da memória principal isso ira funcionar de acordo com sua implementação.

Seria ideal você saber o tamanho exato de toda estrutura de 1 Produto já que você utilizou tamanho fixo para armazenar os dados no arquivo. Sendo assim se você tivesse por exemplo char nome[100]; char cod[100]; int quant; float preco; você poderia fazer o calculo de 100+100+4+4= 208 e criar uma struct com esse valores e assim ler todos eles de uma vez assim:

```
 struct Produtos{

       char nome[100];
       char cod[100];
       int quant;
       float preco;   
};


 struct Produtos prod;  
 fread(&prod,1,208,fp);
```

Espero ter ajudado caso fique dúvidas posso tentar solucionar.